# Insert border in Silverlight tree

Tags: silverlight

[Edit] So specifically I wish to add a precompiled usercontrol to my xaml page, grab the visual tree, find an element based on certain criteria and draw a rectangle around it. The part of the problem this question relates to is dynamically applying a border to an existing in place element.

I've made it work (badly) in code, navigating the tree is fine, but inserting a border between an existing item and its parent causes chaos. It might alter the Z-order, change the order of existing child items, nasty flickering as it is removed from the tree temporarily, events firing.

If this was WPF I could probably use an adorner, but we don't have adorners in SL.

I'm trying to pick an element in my visual tree, buttons in this case, and add a border if it is selected, and remove the border if it is not. It would be simplicity itself if I could just add borders to the xaml and bind their thickness or something, but that's not an option. I specifically want to "discover" elements and highlight them.

Anyone achieved this?

Comment: Usually you would use the `VisualStateManager` and create the border within the control template regardless. You can then change the state of the border using a storyboard activated by the VSM. Usually setting the brush or child opacity to 0 does the trick (there are quite a few controls that do this such as Telerik controls). Your button should activate the visual state based on it's current state (so when the user selects a button it should activate a "Selected" visual state). It's often a whole lot easier to do all of this stuff in Blend.

Comment: There's some good info here: http://ajdotnet.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/silverlight-bitspieces-the-first-steps-with-visual-state-manager/

Comment: Actually that's a great little write up on the VSM. I should have been more explicit in the question, but the xaml controls exist already and won't be modified, I'm specifically looking to dynamically find a control and highlight it. I'll update the question a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your update you could approach this in a few ways I suppose.

One way is to ensure the control sits in a `Grid` (if it doesn't add a grid) and then put a border control behind it, letting the `Grid` overlap the two elements.

```
<SomeContainingElement>
    <Grid>
        <Border></Border>
        <TheButton></TheButton>
    </Grid>
</SomeContainingElement>
```

If you need to ensure that the control doesn't overlap the border, add a margin to the target control so that the border will show up behind it.

```
<SomeContainingElement>
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderThickness="1"></Border>
        <TheButton Margin="1"></TheButton>
    </Grid>
</SomeContainingElement>
```

This way you can just set the visibility of the border to visible/collapsed without affecting the original control. You could even bind the visibility to a property on the control.

If you were to wrap this functionality in a `UserControl` which subclassed `ContentControl`, you could easily just add the button as content and bind a dependency property to control to borders appearance:

```
<SomeContainingElement>
    <YourBorderControl BorderVisibility="{Binding Selected, ElementName=childButton}" BorderThickess="1">
        <TheButton x:Name="childButton" Margin="1"></TheButton>
    </YourBorderControl>
</SomeContainingElement>
```

The grid in the UC could apply padding to it's children based on the border thickness that you set on the UC to ensure the child control doesn't overlap the border sitting behind it in the visual tree.

Edit: or you could just put the border on top..?!

As for discovery - you can just walk the whole control tree and add these controls in before you attempt to use the highlight functionality - saves you having to add/remove anything

Edit: or just add the control upon discovery - that way you only have to write code to insert a visual element in the tree, the UC would handle hiding/showing the border from then on

Comment: Looking good. I think your comment about "just put the border on top" is nearest to what I'm getting to work. I'm using a button as the example for the moment, but you know how these things go. Button today, world domination tomorrow :/ I'm currently trying to make a control sit on top of all other controls, but PopUps are causing me some head aches. If you have a feel for that problem pop a comment on :)

Comment: (What I'm thinking is replacing the root visual with my custom host to get around some of the issues I'm facing, although popups still don't play properly imo. They're in the tree, they just don't honour ZIndex or anything else, only the order they are added.)

Answer (score -1):

It's usual to "visible/collapse" something after "discovering" something else not to add/remove it.

Comment: No, the original xaml is not necessarily available (for the sake of argument). I just want to be able to instanciate a usercontrol, iterate over its elements and pop a border around one.